# Probability Conjecture

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I think there is a flaw in my logic but I'm not sure where it would be.

Let HHH denote the event of three coin flips. Let E(HHH) be the expected value of the number of coin flips until HHH.

Let E(HHH|T) be the expected value of the total number of coin flips until HHH given we just flipped a tails. Let P(H) be the probability of flipping a heads.

Conjecture:

E(HHH)=2+P(HH)E(HHH|HH)+P(HT)E(HHH|HT)+P(TH)E(HHH|TH)+P(TT)E(HHH|TT)

We know E(HHH)=14. (By Simulation)

We know P(H)=.5

We know E(HHH)=1+P(H)E(HHH|H)+P(T)E(HHH|T)

We know E(HHH|T)=1+E(HHH)

Thus E(HHH|H)=11

We know E(HHH|H)=1+P(H)E(HHH|HH)+P(T)E(HHH|HT)

We know E(HHH|HT)=2+E(HHH)

Thus E(HHH|HH)=4.

However, when tested this idea in the simulation, I got answer where E(HHH|HH)≈5. Is the logic invalid or is my simulation faulty?

Answer (score 1):

You have the conjecture that the expected count of tosses until the third consecutive head is:

$$\small\rm \mathsf E({HHH}) = 2 + \mathsf P({HH})\mathsf E({HHH}\mid { HH})+\mathsf P({HT})\mathsf E({HHH}\mid {HT})+\mathsf P({TH})\mathsf E({HHH}\mid {TH})+\mathsf P({TT})\mathsf E({HHH}\mid {TT})$$

Your logic flops on the miss-identification of the conditional expectations.   To fit with your conjecture $\mathsf E({\rm HHH}\mid {\rm ???})$ must be the expected count of *further* tosses until a third consecutive head is encountered when given the latest tosses.

Now the expected count of *further* tosses until a third consecutive head given the prior toss was a tail is equal to the expected count of tosses until a third consecutive head.   And similarly

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E({\rm HHH}) ~=&~ \mathsf E({\rm HHH}\mid {\rm T})\\[1ex] =&~\rm \mathsf E(HHH\mid HT)\\[1ex]=&~\rm \mathsf E(HHH\mid TT)\\[2ex] \rm \mathsf E(HHH\mid HH) ~=&~\rm 1+\mathsf P(H)+\mathsf P(T)\mathsf E(HHH) \\[2ex]\rm \mathsf E(HHH\mid TH)~=&~\rm \mathsf E(HHH\mid H)\\[1ex] ~=&~\rm 1+\mathsf P(H)\mathsf E(HHH\mid HH)+\mathsf P(T)\mathsf E(HHH)\\[1ex]=&~\rm 1+\mathsf P(H)(1+\mathsf P(H))+(\mathsf P(T)+1)\mathsf P(T)\mathsf E(HHH)
\end{align}$$

Then the conjecture is :

$$\rm \mathsf E({HHH}) = 2 + \mathsf P(H)^2\mathsf E({HHH}\mid { HH})+\mathsf P(T)\mathsf P(H)\mathsf E({HHH}\mid {H})+\mathsf P(T)\mathsf E({HHH})$$

and so on...

$$\rm \mathsf E(HHH) =\dfrac{1+\mathsf P(H)+\mathsf P(H)^2}{1-\mathsf P(T)(1+\mathsf P(H)+\mathsf P(H)^2)} = 14$$

Comment: I think your definition of E(HHH|T) differs from mine. My definition would say that E(HHH|T) >= 4. Whereas your definition would say E(HHH|T) >= 3 because you don't count the flips given. Is there a reason why you made this change?

Comment: @Michael Because it fits the conjecture: "The expected tosses until the target equals *two plus* the iterated expectation of *some* tosses given the first two." $$\underbrace{\mathsf E(X)=2+}_{\text{count the first two}}\underbrace{\mathsf P(HH)\mathsf E(X\mid HH)+\mathsf P(TH)\mathsf E(X\mid TH)+\mathsf P(HT)\mathsf E(X\mid HT)+\mathsf P(TT)\mathsf E(X\mid TT)}_{\text{therefore, this must count }\textem{further}\text{ tosses}}$$

Comment: Hm. I sorta see where you are coming from, however I'm still not sure how I implicitly switched definitions. Do you have any literature on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

One of your errors is when you say $E(HHH|T)=1+E(HHH)$, as you should have $E(HHH|T)=E(HHH)$, and I also doubt your simulation of $E(HHH|HH)\approx 5$

I would have thought you should have:

- $E(H)=E(H|T)=2$
- $E(HH)=E(HH|T)=6$
- $E(HHH)=E(HHH|T)=14$

suggesting

- $E(HH|H)=1+\frac12\times 0+ \frac12 \times E(HH|T) = 4$
- $E(HHH|HH)=1+\frac12\times 0+\frac12 \times E(HHH|T) = 8$
- $E(HHH|H)=1+\frac12 E(HHH|HH)+\frac12 \times E(HHH|T) = 12$

and you can then check theses are consistent with my original assertions since

- $E(H) = 1+\frac12\times 0 + \frac12 \times E(H|T) = 2$
- $E(HH) = 1+ \frac12 \times E(HH|H) + \frac12 \times E(HH|T) = 6$
- $E(HHH) = 1+ \frac12 \times E(HHH|H) + \frac12 \times E(HHH|T) = 14$